# ManyChat, Zapir and JavaScript; how to send out different messages per the end result

Tags: javascript, zapier

I am trying to create questionnaire (15 questions)in my Messenger with the two possible answers Yes and No. Each answer has value (Yes..3) and (No..1). I create Zap where I calculate number like result. I create Java script code by Zapier  like next step and here my knowledge is finished. I code to calculate number and like next step sending the message back with answer like number.

What I want from `javascript` code by Zapier is to calculate answers and based on the results send the answer to Subscriber who answer the Questionnaire.

The answer message according to the scoring answers should be following:

```
<26
"messege"

26-35
"messege"

>35
"messege"
```

Here it is how I made until now (sorry but answers are in Slovene language...not important):

```
return {
  calculatednumber: Number(inputData.q1) + Number(inputData.q2) + Number(inputData.q3) + Number(inputData.q4) + Number(inputData.q5) + Number(inputData.q6) + Number(inputData.q7) + Number(inputData.q8) + Number(inputData.q9) + Number(inputData.q10) + Number(inputData.q11) + Number(inputData.q12) + Number(inputData.q13) + Number(inputData.q14) + Number(inputData.q15)
 }

if (calculatednumber ==='<25') {
  return []; //"Videti je, da so vaše prehranske navade ustrezne. Za izboljšanje priporočamo jemanje multivitaminskih/mineralnih tablet!"
  }

if (calculatednumber ==='26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35') {
  return []; //"Multivitaminski/mineralni dodatek k prehrani bo vašemu telesu pomagal ohraniti esencialna hranila, ki jih potrebuje, skupaj z drugimi označenimi dodatki!"
  }

if (calculatednumber ==='>36') {
  return []; //"Vnos multivitaminov/mineralov bi vam zagotovo koristil. Z bolj uravnoteženo prehrano in dodatkom multivitaminov/mineralov pa bi potrebovali še vnos drugih vitaminov/mineralov!"
  };
```

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Are you using any of the https://botmakers.net/chatbot-templates/explore/manychat templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track! Some pointers:

- You'll only ever call one `return` function, so you don't want to use it for the variable at the top.
- You don't need to nest the variable inside an object; it can just be a number
- the `calculatedNumber` variable will never be equal to `"<25"` because that's a string with a character in it, so your logic branches don't work.

Try this instead:

```
let calculatedNumber = Number(inputData.q1) + Number(inputData.q2) // + ...

if (calculatedNumber < 25) {
    return {message: 'Small Message'}  // it's important to return an object
} else if (calculatedNumber > 36) {
    return {message: 'Large Message'}
} else {
    // everything inbetween 25 and 36
    return {message: 'Medium Message'}
}
```

Anyway, I'd recommend reading through https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/javascript/ to get a better handle on some of the syntax fundamentals.

Comment: No problem. If this worked, make sure to upvote the answer and mark it as correct!